# python Selenium send_keys to a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to automate input to a Jupyter notebook with selenium in python.

I am attempting to use the send_keys() method with various elements within the DOM and all that I have tried so far have the following issue:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span> is not reachable by keyboard
```

So far I have attempted locators that return the following elemets:

- ('tag name', 'textarea') [However, this is hidden and therefore not interactable]
- ('tag name', 'pre') under the ('class', 'CodeMirror-code') element
- ('tag name', 'span') under the ('class', 'CodeMirror-code') element
- ('tag name', 'span') under the span above

There is no apparent `input` in the DOM that can be seen.  Has anyone attempted to automate a Jupyter notebook?

It appears that when manually typing into the textarea on the screen the DOM is dynamically changing the `span` elements below...

Here is the relevant part of the DOM I am working with and a screenshot of the textarea [image: input]

```
<div class="cell code_cell rendered selected" tabindex="2">
   <div class="input">
      <div class="run_this_cell" title="Run this cell"><i class="fa-step-forward fa"></i></div>
      <div class="prompt input_prompt"><bdi>In</bdi>&nbsp;[&nbsp;]:</div>
      <div class="inner_cell">
         <div class="ctb_hideshow">
            <div class="celltoolbar"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="input_area">
            <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-ipython">
               <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 5.59375px; left: 5.59375px;"><textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; bottom: -1em; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;"></textarea></div>
               <div class="CodeMirror-vscrollbar" cm-not-content="true">
                  <div style="min-width: 1px; height: 0px;"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="CodeMirror-hscrollbar" cm-not-content="true">
                  <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
               <div class="CodeMirror-gutter-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
               <div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1">
                  <div class="CodeMirror-sizer" style="margin-left: 0px; min-width: 8.59375px; margin-bottom: -15px; border-right-width: 15px; min-height: 28px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                     <div style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="CodeMirror-lines" role="presentation">
                           <div role="presentation" style="position: relative; outline: none;">
                              <div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
                              <div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
                              <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></div>
                              <div class="CodeMirror-cursors" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                 <div class="CodeMirror-cursor" style="left: 5.59375px; top: 0px; height: 17px;">&nbsp;</div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="CodeMirror-code" role="presentation">
                                 <pre class=" CodeMirror-line " role="presentation"><span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;"><span cm-text="">​</span></span></pre>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="position: absolute; height: 15px; width: 1px; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; top: 28px;"></div>
                  <div class="CodeMirror-gutters" style="display: none; height: 43px;"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="output_wrapper">
      <div class="out_prompt_overlay prompt" title="click to expand output; double click to hide output"></div>
      <div class="output"></div>
      <div class="btn btn-default output_collapsed" title="click to expand output" style="display: none;">. . .</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**
I have been successful when changing the DOM with javascript execution by making the `textarea` visible and then sending keys to it. (This was done by removing `hidden;` from the `style` attribute in the parent `div` element that it inherited from. However, I am looking for a solution which does not require altering the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use sendKeys() on an element that is not a text input or textarea.

Instead try using Actions, after clicking the target element:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.SendKeys("My input").Perform();
```

I tested this on a jsfiddle.net (which doesn't use a standard textarea either) and it did the job.

My example is in c#, the Python documentation for performing action chaining can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't send keys to the text-area since it is not visible, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes I know you can use actions to send keys to non-textareas and input elements. Try it.